# How to programatically set ?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem on a TextView

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to set the text appearance of a textview I have in a custom adapter in the navigation drawer. I want to make some items' text to be smaller than the others (like google music's navigation drawer). So I have an if statement in the getView method I want to use the default android styles for list items.

I know I can do the following:

```
textView.setTextAppearance(getContext(), android.R.style.TextAppearance_Small);
```

But I can't find a android.R.style value for the textAppearanceListItem attribute that you can set in xml with:

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem"
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me:

```
textView.setTextAppearance(getContext(), android.R.attr.textAppearanceListItem);
```

Comment: Is the textAppearanceListItem only available for a ListView?  If so, is there a comparable attribute available for a RecyclerView?

Comment: @AJW Comments are for comments, not for questions. You have a question, well, ask it, that's what SO exists for. Upper Right Corner of the page -> "Ask Question" ;-)

Comment: Ok I am newbie to SO so still learning protocols and etiquette.  I appreciate the feedback and will ask questions using upper right.

Comment: @AJW When you ask "real questions" you will reach a lot more people here (everybody here will see that question easily, most people don't see questions in comments other than the owner of the post you comment) and only then you can earn reputation for asking the question and other users for answering it, which is how everything on SO works.

Answer (score 1):

`setTextAppearance` requires `@StyleRes int resId`, while `android.R.attr.textAppearanceListItem` is an `attr`, so it won't work.

Looking into Android frameworks source code, the style varies according to app theme. In the material theme for example, it's defined to `@style/TextAppearance.Material.ListItem`:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-11.0.0_r48/core/res/res/values/themes_material.xml#124

And that style is defined to `TextAppearance.Material.Subhead`:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-11.0.0_r48/core/res/res/values/styles_material.xml#498

---

So one solution is just use that style value directly:

```
textView.setTextAppearance(android.R.style.TextAppearance_Material_Subhead);
```

---

Or you may want to resolve it's value based on current theme, which can be more verbose:

```
TypedValue value = new TypedValue();
context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.textAppearanceListItem, value, true);
textView.setTextAppearance(value.resourceId);
```

---

If you use kotlin, `splitties-resources` is more convenient:

```
textView.textAppearance = context.resolveThemeAttribute(android.R.attr.textAppearanceListItem)
```

Read its documents here: https://github.com/LouisCAD/Splitties/blob/v3.0.0/modules/resources/README.md